# Does Implements works only with interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, implements

Learning a little-bit about java `Interfaces` and `Implements` made me question ,

1. if Inheritance works only with classes does the `Implements` work only with `Interfaces` , or it may has another uses?
2. Does java has to offer us "built-in" `Interfaces` that we can `Implements` into our program without creating it? and if so where i can find a list of those.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can only implement interfaces. 2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: There are literally _hundreds_ of `interface`s you can implement in Java for all sorts of reasons. But yes, you `extends` a class and `implements` an `interface`. Unless you are an `interface`, then you `extends` an `interface`.

Comment: class might `extends` another class and `implements` interfaces, yes implements is used only for implementing interfaces. By build in interfaces, do you mean one from java api?

Comment: Recommended reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if Inheritance works only with classes does the Implements work only with Interfaces , or it may has another uses?

Inheritance in general can apply to classes *and* interfaces through the use of the `extends` keyword.  That is to say, a class can inherit properties and functions from another class, whereas an interface can expand its contractual obligations from another interface.

Example:

```
public interface Phone {
    String getNumber();
}

public interface MobilePhone extends Phone {
    public boolean isSmartPhone();
}
```

If one were to implement the `MobilePhone` interface above, they'd also have to implement the `getNumber()` method as well.

As for `implements` - that **only** works with interfaces.

> Does java has to offer us "built-in" Interfaces that we can Implements into our program without creating it? and if so where i can find a list of those.

They're not "built-in" per se; they're prewritten for you in Java.  The [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is the best place to look for first-party interfaces; however, it's worth noting that you can  get third-party interfaces from other packages and frameworks, such as Spring, Guice, and Guava, or from some other developer's JAR that you happen to include in your project.

Comment: with that being said , i got another question if you may.. 1. does interfaces have purpose if i work on a project myself? 2. why the `Implements` exist if the `Extends` can do the same and more?

Comment: 1.  There may be times in which you want to create an abstraction but implement it in a few different ways to suit performance or testing needs.  2.  `extends` is conceptually different than `implements`; `implements` enforces a compile-time contractual obligation with its implementor.  [This reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) should help with understanding the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Only interfaces can be implemented.

JAVA have many builtin interface that you can implement based on your requirement.

More than that a class can implement only interface while it can extend more than one class